# Rails Upvote AJAX not working properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So my upvote link is replacing the vote counter for all the links instead of the individual one. Help?

**Controller**

```
  def upcount
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.upcount
    @category.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to categories_path(@category)}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag category.image.url(:large) %>
      <div class="caption">
        <%= category.name %> - <%= category.quote %></p>
        <%= link_to "Upvote", upcount_category_path(category), method: "put", remote: true %>
        <div id="total-votes">
          <%= category.count %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Upcount.js.erb**

```
$("#total-votes").html("<%= @category.count %>")
```

Clicking the second link will turn the replace the first and second link with 15. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Let try with the link_to 'Upvote' without option 'remote: true'?

Comment: @brian Lau i think your link or div for up-vote first and second has same id `total-votes` so this thing happened

Comment: @VishalJAIN you're right, i wasn't sure how to fix it, but luckily you saved the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML ids are meant to be unique. Your duplication of the "total-votes" id is resulting in invalid HTML. It is also confusing your javascript, as it doesn't know which div you want to target.

You can fix this by adding the category id to the html id like `total-votes-<%= category.id %>`, so that it is unique for all.

Full example:

**View file**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag category.image.url(:large) %>
      <div class="caption">
        <%= category.name %> - <%= category.quote %></p>
        <%= link_to "Upvote", upcount_category_path(category), method: "put", remote: true %>
        <div id="total-votes-<%= category.id %>">
          <%= category.count %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Upcount.js.erb**

```
$("#total-votes-<%= @category.id %>").html("<%= @category.count %>")
```